# Jquery.validate.js Validation - Using 2 remotes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using the built in remote method in [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), I can refer to a PHP file. This works fine when I want to do this just once for one condition, but how would I include a second remote method to evaluate a second condition?

Here's how I include just one remote:

```
right_form_url: {
     required: true,
     image: true,
     gif: true,
     remote: "imagecheck.php"
   }
```

Is it possible to do something like:

`remote_2: "file.php"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify them as an array

```
remote: ["imagecheck.php", "file.php", "file2.php"] //and so on
```